# Need help with optimizing "not in" query

Tags: sql, self-join

I have an SQL query that I am looking to optimize.

```
SELECT * 
FROM QUEUE_SMS_ALERT Q1
where ALERT_ORIGIN = "FOO" 
AND RECORD_ID is null 
and PHONE NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT PHONE 
    FROM QUEUE_SMS_ALERT Q2 
    where Q2.ALERT_ORIGIN = "BAR"
);
```

Basically need to get all rows where ALERT_ORIGIN is "FOO" Which do not have a corresponding row in the same table with ALERT_ORIGIN "BAR". The table contains abt 17000 rows and there are only abt 1000 records with ALERT_ORIGIN "BAR". So my query is supposed to give me abt 16000 rows.

EDIT : The current query is very slow. I do not have any indexes currently.

Comment: Do you have indexes, keys etc? Is it slow now? Is PHONE nullable?

Comment: Consider putting indexes on columns `ALERT_ORIGIN` and `PHONE`

Comment: And you can remove the `DISTINCT` from the `...PHONE NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT PHONE ...`, it's not needed.

Comment: @Shreyas, which version of SQL (Oracle, SQLServer, MySQL, etc.) are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing that you have NULL values in the phone column which means NOT IN doesn't work (so it's "fix" not "optimise"). So I've written it with NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT *
FROM QUEUE_SMS_ALERT Q1 
WHERE
    Q1.ALERT_ORIGIN = 'FOO'
    AND
    Q1.RECORD_ID is null
    AND 
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
        FROM QUEUE_SMS_ALERT Q2
        WHERE 
            Q2.ALERT_ORIGIN = 'BAR'
            AND
            Q1.PHONE = Q2.PHONE)
```

If it is slow rather than "wrong" then you need to use indexes. What do you have now?
For this query, you need an index on `(ALERT_ORIGIN, PHONE, RECORD_ID)`.

Note: use single quotes for string delimiters

Comment: Why did you include `RECORD_ID` in the index suggestion? This column can be NULL, which might make the index less useful for this query.

Comment: @a'r: It's in the WHERE clause. NULLs are indexed too.

Comment: @gbn, it depends on the database. NULLs are not always indexed in Oracle for example.

Comment: @a'r: In SQL Server an index entry has the NULL bitmap. Anyway, OP is happy :-)